# How can I count users which have come to the Telegram Bot before pressing /start?

Tags: python, analytics, telegram-bot

Is there any method, how can I calculate the amount of newcomers to the Telegram Bot by the link @somelinktobot? On that step, users haven't already pressed the button `/start`.

To describe the problem more precisely, the step I would like to measure to is shown on the screenshot: [screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNViG.png)

In advance, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any ways to know how many people have visited your/your bot's profile on Telegram.

There are a few scam bots promising such possibility but none is true.

You can read all the available methods for bot api [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/).

Other than these methods there are no other publicly known methods.

Answer (score 0):

When the users land on the Telegram chatbot "Start" page they haven't interacted yet with your bot therefore you cannot capture any information or data.
One option is to measure the traffic on the page which sends the users to Telegram.

For example if you have a web page with the link to your bot

```
https://telegram.me/MyChatbot?start=value
```

you can have analytics on that page using existing tools (ie Google Analytics Event Tracker can count the click on a link) or you can implement something yourself (using Javascript send a request to your tracking tool)